# Adding placeholder to django-taggit field - TaggableManager()

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with a `TaggableManager()` field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    knowledge_topics = TaggableManager(
        verbose_name="Áreas de conocimiento",
        help_text=_("Una lista de temas separada por comas.")
    )
```

I want to add placeholder to `knowledge_topics` field. My form is:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = "Detalles del anfitrión de estudios"
    knowledge_topics = forms.CharField(label='Áreas de conocimiento',
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'placeholder': 'Una lista de temas separada por comas'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('knowledge_topics',)
```

But when I go to my form, the placeholder does not work properly, What can I do to fix this:

Comment: in forms set the value of your input to ""

Comment: My apologies, I cannot understand your suggest ... in the placeholder attribute?